# Usigne ical4j.jar with Java, set parameter X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN

Tags: java, eclipse, calendar

How can i set this parameter X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN: to TRUE WHEN creating a new .ics file ? in VEvent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brief Description on X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee203486(v=exchg.80).aspx

For set this parameter X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN :

```
Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
calendar.getProperties().add(new XProperty("X-MS-OLK-FORCEINSPECTOROPEN" , "TRUE"));
```